# Popup Subview with Transparent Background

Tags: ios, swift

I created simple popup in `tableview` however I do not know how to make the subview transparent, right now it is full black.

This is how I created the popup inside tableview cell button click:

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RatingViewController") as! RatingViewController
                    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
                    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(200, 100)

                    if let presentationController = vc.popoverPresentationController {
                        presentationController.delegate = self
                        presentationController.permittedArrowDirections = .up
                        presentationController.sourceView = self.view
                        presentationController.sourceRect = CGRect(0, 0, 50, 50)

                        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
```

What should I do to make it transparent? My subview for the RatingViewController is white but for some reason it shows as black.